# A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to concat two string using sql query. Below is my code which is not working.

```
SELECT TOP 100 CONCAT('James ','Stephen') AS [Column1] 
FROM [dbo].[ORDERS] 
Group BY () 
ORDER BY CONCAT('James ','Stephen') ASC
```

If I use `[Column1]` instead of `CONCAT('James ','Stephen')` in Order by clause, it seems working.

```
SELECT TOP 100 CONCAT('James ','Stephen') AS [Column1] 
FROM [dbo].[ORDERS] 
Group by () 
ORDER BY [Column1] ASC
```

Can anyone explain me, why did not the first query work?

Comment: You can try to concat using the operator "+". I don't understand well what do you want with that group by ()

Comment: In addition, order by a fixed string makes no sense, because all the records will have the same order

Comment: What is the point of your query?

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you "you've asked me to do something that doesn't really make sense". Finding a way to re-formulate the query such that it doesn't raise the error but keeps the logic the same is just demonstrating that you can trick the compiler sometimes. The query still doesn't *make sense*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORDER BY clause is to be used with columns from underlyring tables. You cannot order by constants.

This is explained in the documentation

> Specifies a column or expression on which to sort the query result
>   set. A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias, or a
>   nonnegative integer representing the position of the column in the
>   select list.

[ORDER BY documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql)

Note that you can use an expression, such as ORDER BY CONCAT(field1, field2), but it makes no sense to try to sort by a hard coded string which would obviously be the same for every record.

You can get around this by referencing the alias, but this is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql)

> A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias, or a nonnegative integer representing the position of the column in the select list.
>
> Multiple sort columns can be specified. Column names must be unique. The sequence of the sort columns in the ORDER BY clause defines the organization of the sorted result set. That is, the result set is sorted by the first column and then that ordered list is sorted by the second column, and so on.

However in first query you not specified neither a name or column alias nor position of the column in select list